# Using a single method to clean data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Since security is always something that is a concern, is it fine to just use the following method whenever I need to clean data that I don't know is safe?

```
function clean_data($input) {
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($input))));
}
```

Or is something that I shouldn't do?

Comment: Just use prepared statements / parameterized queries with mysqli or pdo and you wont have to worry about escaping data for db queries.

Comment: What have `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars` to do with DB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/130323/285587

Comment: What you have is useless at best and potentionally dangerous.

Comment: There is no "Catch All" solution to sanitizing DB input. It needs to be specific to the type of input you expect to receive.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: my suggestion is a catch all solution ;)

Comment: @JimL, I was planning on using this to clean URL parameters like `file.php?title=VALUEHERE`, not for queries.

Comment: @John: then htmlspecialchars should do, or (int) $var / (float) $var if they're numbers.

Comment: It just doesn't work like that. Like that in your case is: putting a condom on your car, adding a parachute, adding a bumper and putting a helmet on the roof.

Comment: @John. 1. Your question is tagged with mysql and mysqli. 2. You are doing mysqli_real_escape_string. And now you says it is not for the query?